# How to navigate PHP-based pagination with WGET?

Tags: windows, php, regex, wget, javascript

I'm trying to come up with a list of possible names for our next baby boy and have been looking through the site [IndiaParenting](http://www.indiaparenting.com/babynames/hindu-boy-names.php).  Each name on the site has a detail page at a URL like this one `http://www.indiaparenting.com/babynames/meaning-of-Aadesh.shtml`.  I'd like the name to be similar to our firstborn and am trying to do the following:

- WGET all pages from the site which contains "meaning-of" to a single folder on my hard drive, with something like `wget -nc -c -nd -r -l1 -k http://www.indiaparenting.com/babynames/hindu-boy-names.php -A "meaning-of*" -I /babynames`
- Do something like `dir > filenames.txt` to put everything into a single text file.
- Parse the generated file for a specific regex to find possible names.  First son's name is Ranveer, and we're looking for names that start with either N or R, so the regex is probably something like: `[NR][aeiou][^aeiou][^aeiou][aeiou]{2}[^aeiou]`.
- Manually go through final list with the Madam & choose a name!

The problem I'm having is with the wget.  The page is created with PHP and at the bottom there is a page navigator which doesn't link to another page's URL like normal:

[image: Paging section]

I looked and found the JS pagingFunction:

```
function pagingFunction(labelName){         
    vpage = document.getElementById("pageNum");     
    pageNm = labelName;         
    vpage.value = pageNm;
    document.getElementById("frmPaging").submit();      
}
```

**Question: I had thought that recursively WGETting the pages would go page by page, but it does not.  Is there a way to handle this with WGET?  If not, is there another option?**

---

Other information: I thought about generating a list based on the regex, but it would be too long and have too many invalid names anyway, which is why I'd like to base it off of actual names from one of these baby names sites.  I am also going to contact the site to see if they are able to just run a query on their DB and put the names in a file for me, and if all else fails, there are other sites to check out.

Answer (score 0):

This site has a particularly odd design. Just a note, though, PHP doesn't make a difference here.

It looks like they load pages with the following method:

1. Clicking the link executes some JS.
2. This JS fills in a hidden form with the page number.
3. The script then submits the form, which makes a POST request to the server.
4. The server responds directly with the relevant page.

You have a couple of options here. The easiest is to simply script a `wget` request with `--post-data` in a loop to retrieve all pages from 1 to n. Refer to the documentation and your browser's network monitor to find out what the actual request is. For example, this is what Firefox's network monitor says the request body is:

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 145

pagingQuery=select+*+from+tblbabynames+where+++religion%3D%27hindu%27+and+gender%3D%27M%27+limit+0%2C30&totalRows=3097&pageNum=2&searchResultNo=0
```

You can probably replace the `pageNum=2` in a loop.

A more involved method would be to use a browser automation toolkit like Selenium to literally navigate through and *click* the links, activating the JS just as a human would.